# How would you write a window service in java using apache daemon

Tags: java, windows

I searched for examples for java classes as window service, but I can't find good examples for it.
So please, show me some example code for just start and stop the service; being that when the service is started some text should be printed out and stop the service.

**NOTE**: I'm using Apache Daemon API.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There is [extensive documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html) for this project including examples. What exactly do you miss?